# How to remove PageView's leading space in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-pageview

I implemented images carousel by using `PageView` and research about it for a moment and then I archived this result.

[image]

As you see, I got extra space in front of first item in PageView. I have no idea to remove it. Has anyone ever did it ? Thank you so much

**My PageView Class**

```
List<String> images = [
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQTIZccfNPnqalhrWev-Xo7uBhkor57_rKbkw&usqp=CAU",
  "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/4684322/screenshots/18696799/media/722072055e079b1b7c88b1894a1128d7.png?compress=1&resize=1000x750&vertical=top"
];
return Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 200,
  child: PageView.builder(
    itemCount: 2,
    pageSnapping: true,
    controller: _pageController,
    itemBuilder: (context, pagePosition) {
      return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            child: Image.network(
              images[pagePosition],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ));
    },
  ),
);
```

PageView Controller

```
_pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);
```

Comment: use carousel_slider package for that dont waste your time as like me :D

Comment: @VishalPatel Hahaha I agree with you!! But My team's vision want to remove unnecessary library as much as we can. TT

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

After I take deep inside PageView class, I just tried every constructor properties ( T_T ) and got solution.

`padEnds: false`

set it in constructor of PageView

```
PageView.builder(
   itemCount: 2,
   padEnds: false,
   pageSnapping: true
   itemBuilder: (context, pagePosition) {
      return Container();
   },
)
```

If anyone has another solution, you can tell me? :)

Answer (score 1):

Change viewportFraction: 1 instead of 0.8;

```
_pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and ran it. There was no problem. It is suggested to change it as follows:

```
return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            child: Image.asset("asset/bb.jpeg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: double.infinity,
            )
          ))
```

[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvCek.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put controller on question. I updated it.